# Running Apache as a service on Windows 2008-account not allowed to log on

Tags: windows-server-2008, apache-2.4

Not a Windows guru, so I'm hoping I'm just missing something easy here...OK, here's my scenario:
I am attempting to run Apache on our Windows 2008 server using a new local account called “ApacheSu” that is a member of Users.

The account was granted “Log on as a service” and “Act as part of the operating system” privileges through group policy as required by Apache documentation for running the web server as a service.

When I switch the Apache service to log on as my local account, the service fails to start because the account “is not allowed to logon at this computer”.

The failure information section gives the status as 0xc000006e (status account restriction) and the substatus as 0xc0000070 (workstation restriction).

The translation of 0xc000006e is as follows:

```
1. The username and password are correct, but there is an account restriction on the user account (such as valid workstation, valid logon hours, etc.). The value under SubStatus should provide the restriction details.
2. Active Directory Replication may not be complete
```

And this is the translation of 0xc0000070:

```
1. The user is trying to logon from a machine they aren’t assigned to.
2. Active Directory replication may not be complete
```

The second item is common to both status codes, but as far as I know, Active Directory groups don’t include local accounts, so I don’t think that’s the issue.  (But then, I'm not a network engineer or sysadmin.)
The status suggests the substatus should provide the details.  The substatus says that the user is trying to logon from a machine they aren’t assigned to.  That doesn’t seem to make sense to me, as the account is local to the machine....I'm not sure if I've missed something in setting up Apache to run as a service, or whether there's a policy or permissions issue.  Any ideas?  Thanks for any help you can provide...Here is the full text from the event log:

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          10/15/2015 5:05:58 PM
Event ID:      4625
Task Category: Logon
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Failure
User:          N/A
Computer:      Y99WS.xxxx.something.com
Description:
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       Y99WS$
    Account Domain:     xxxx
    Logon ID:       0x3e7

Logon Type:         5 

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       ApacheSu
    Account Domain:     Y99WS

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     User not allowed to logon at this computer.
    Status:         0xc000006e  
    Sub Status:     0xc0000070  

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x230
    Caller Process Name:    C:\Windows\System32\services.exe

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   Y99WS
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      Advapi  
    Authentication Package: Negotiate
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0

This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.

The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.

The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
    - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
    - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
    - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" />
    <EventID>4625</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>0</Level>
    <Task>12544</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8010000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-10-15T21:05:58.353398000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>2212241</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="568" ThreadID="1436" />
    <Channel>Security</Channel>
    <Computer>Y99WS.xxxx.something.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-5-18</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserName">Y99WS$</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">xxxx</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x3e7</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetUserSid">S-1-0-0</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetUserName">ApacheSu</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetDomainName">Y99WS</Data>
    <Data Name="Status">0xc000006e</Data>
    <Data Name="FailureReason">%%2312</Data>
    <Data Name="SubStatus">0xc0000070</Data>
    <Data Name="LogonType">5</Data>
    <Data Name="LogonProcessName">Advapi  </Data>
    <Data Name="AuthenticationPackageName">Negotiate</Data>
    <Data Name="WorkstationName">Y99WS</Data>
    <Data Name="TransmittedServices">-</Data>
    <Data Name="LmPackageName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="KeyLength">0</Data>
    <Data Name="ProcessId">0x230</Data>
    <Data Name="ProcessName">C:\Windows\System32\services.exe</Data>
    <Data Name="IpAddress">-</Data>
    <Data Name="IpPort">-</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared to have been the HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA\crashonauditfail registry key.  It was set to 2 after the Security event log filled and would not allow non-admins to log on to the machine, even after emptying the log.